# Qlik -create calculated Dimension to show barchart from month start untill filter date(5-4-4 calendar)

Tags: date, calendar, qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression

I have a master calendar(5-4-4) that look like the below image.

[image: Master calender]

I have a Date column in the Sales table. I'm using that Date column in the Selection pane(Filter).

**Example Scenario:**

now I selected Selection pane date '15-10-2020', bar-chart only showing '15-10-2020' sales only. but I need to look up the master calendar and show the dimension from the start_month date to until selected date

**Expected Output:** bar chart needs to show dimensions from
'28-09-2020' to '15-10-2020'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach is to generate dates from `Start_Month` to `TransDate` (made up field name)

Lets say that this is the data we have:

```
Transactions:
Load * inline [
TransDate , Value
15-10-2020, 100
27-07-2021, 50
];

MasterCalendar_Temp:
Load * inline [
Start_Month, End_Month , Month_number
28-09-2020 , 01-11-2020, 1
02-11-2020 , 29-11-2020, 2
30-11-2020 , 27-12-2020, 3
28-12-2020 , 31-01-2021, 4
01-02-2021 , 28-02-2021, 5
01-03-2021 , 28-03-2021, 6
29-03-2021 , 02-05-2021, 7
03-05-2021 , 30-05-2021, 8
31-05-2021 , 27-06-2021, 9
28-06-2021 , 01-08-2021, 10
02-08-2021 , 29-08-2021, 11
30-08-2021 , 26-09-2021, 12
];
```

The first step is to find in which interval each `TransDate` is part of. For this we'll use [IntervalMatch](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/May2021/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/ScriptPrefixes/IntervalMatch.htm) function

```
Inner Join
IntervalMatch ( TransDate )
Load
  Start_Month,
  End_Month
Resident
  MasterCalendar_Temp
;
```

At this point `MasterCalendar_Temp` table will look like:

So we now know the perid for each `TransDate`

[image: MasterCalendar_Temp]

The next step is to load the `MasterCalendar_Temp` data into a separate table but concatenate `Start_Month` and `TransDate` into one:

```
NoConcatenate

MasterCalendar:
Load 
  Start_Month,
  End_Month,
  Start_Month & '_' & TransDate as Start_TransDate_Temp
Resident MasterCalendar_Temp;

// we dont need this table anymore
Drop Table MasterCalendar_Temp;
```

Once we have it we can start creating our dates

```
// loop through each value in Start_TransDate_Temp field
// for each step extract Start_Month and TransDate values
// use these two values to generate the dates between them
for i = 1 to FieldValueCount('Start_TransDate_Temp')
  let value = FieldValue('Start_TransDate_Temp', $(i));
  let startDate = num(SubField('$(value)', '_', 1));
  let transDate = num(SubField('$(value)', '_', 2));

  Dates:
  LOAD
    date('$(transDate)', 'DD-MM-YYYY') as TransDate,
    date($(startDate) + IterNo() - 1, 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS DisplayDates
  AUTOGENERATE (1)
  WHILE 
    $(startDate) + IterNo() -1 <= $(transDate)
  ;

next

// we dont need this table anymore
Drop Table MasterCalendar;
```

And thats it!

After the script is reloaded we'll have two tables:

[image: data model]

`Transactions` table is untouched and `Dates` table will have values like this:

[image: Dates table]

As you can see for each `TransDate` we have the range of dates (from the correcponding `Start_Month` to `TransDate`

If we construct a simple bar chart (with `DisplayDates` as dimension and `sum(Value)` as measure) and do not apply any selections:

[image: BarChart 1]

And if select one `TransDate`:

[image: BarChart 2]